# How to get columns as row combinations in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in below format:

```
country region  max min
A         R1    141 86
A         R2    215 72
A         R3    473 36
B         R1    384 79
B         R2    439 88
B         R3    172 54
```

I am trying to convert above df to below output with logic as

For A,if first option is max put max measure,rest all min
For other than A,if second option is max,put max measure,rest all min

Note: additional default option (min) is there.

```
country region  measure Option1 Option2
A   R1  86  min min
A   R2  72  min min
A   R3  36  min min
A   R1  86  min max
A   R2  72  min max
A   R3  36  min max
A   R1  86  min default
A   R2  72  min default
A   R3  36  min default
A   R1  86  default min
A   R2  72  default min
A   R3  36  default min
A   R1  86  default default
A   R2  72  default default
A   R3  36  default default
A   R1  86  default max
A   R2  72  default max
A   R3  36  default max
A   R1  141 max min
A   R2  215 max min
A   R3  473 max min
A   R1  141 max default
A   R2  215 max default
A   R3  473 max default
A   R1  141 max max
A   R2  215 max max
A   R3  473 max max
B   R1  79  min min
B   R2  88  min min
B   R3  54  min min
B   R1  384 min max
B   R2  439 min max
B   R3  172 min max
B   R1  79  min default
B   R2  88  min default
B   R3  54  min default
B   R1  79  default min
B   R2  88  default min
B   R3  54  default min
B   R1  79  default default
B   R2  88  default default
B   R3  54  default default
B   R1  384 default max
B   R2  439 default max
B   R3  172 default max
B   R1  79  max min
B   R2  88  max min
B   R3  54  max min
B   R1  79  max default
B   R2  88  max default
B   R3  54  max default
B   R1  384 max max
B   R2  439 max max
B   R3  172 max max
```

I understand that melt option with some trick can work here,but not able to frame it properly being a newbie.

Please help

Edit1:

Achieved using below code:

Can someone help me fine tune it and improve performance?

```
d1 = pd.melt(data, id_vars=['country','region'], value_vars=['max', 'min','default']).sort(['country','region']).reset_index(drop=True)

for ridx,i in enumerate(d1['value']):
    if pd.isnull(i):
        d1['value'].loc[ridx] = d1['value'].loc[ridx-1]
    else:
        pass

d2 = d1

from pandas import DataFrame, merge
d1['key'] = 1
d2['key'] = 1
d3 = merge(d1, d2, on='key')

d3 = d3.drop(['key'],axis=1)

for index, row in d3.iterrows():
    if d3['region_x'].loc[index] == d3['region_y'].loc[index] and d3['country_x'].loc[index] == d3['country_y'].loc[index]:
        pass
    else:
        d3 = d3.drop([index])
d3 = d3.reset_index(drop=True)

d3['rate'] = ""


for index, row in d3.iterrows():
    if d3['country_x'].loc[index] == 'A':
        d3['rate'].loc[index] = d3['value_x'].loc[index]
    else:
        d3['rate'].loc[index] = d3['value_y'].loc[index]

d3 = d3.drop(['value_x','country_y','region_y','value_y'],axis=1)

d3.columns = ['country','region','Option1','Option2','measure']
d3 = d3[['country','region','measure','Option1','Option2']]
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html), [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`numpy.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) and [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
d1 = pd.melt(data, id_vars=['country','region'], value_vars=['max', 'min','default'])
       .sort_values(['country','region']).reset_index(drop=True)

#fill NaN in column value method ffill 
#(propagate last valid observation forward to next valid)
d1['value'] = d1['value'].fillna(method='ffill')

d1['key'] = 1
#you can use double d1
d3 = pd.merge(d1, d1, on='key')
d3 = d3.drop(['key'],axis=1)

#filter columns by conditions - boolean indexing
d3 = d3[(d3['region_x'] == d3['region_y']) & (d3['country_x'] == d3['country_y'])]
        .reset_index(drop=True)

#if condition is true get value_x else value_y
#if neccesarry, convert to int by astype(int)
d3['rate'] = np.where(np.in1d(d3['country_x'], 'A'), d3['value_x'],d3['value_y']).astype(int)

d3 = d3.drop(['value_x','country_y','region_y','value_y'],axis=1)

d3.columns = ['country','region','Option1','Option2','measure']
d3 = d3[['country','region','measure','Option1','Option2']]
```

**Timings**:

New solution is 300 times faster, mainly because no loops `iterrows()`.

```
In [67]: %timeit old(data)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.46 s per loop

In [68]: %timeit new(data1)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.33 ms per loop
```

**Code**:

```
data1 = data.copy()

def old(data):
    d1 = pd.melt(data, id_vars=['country','region'], value_vars=['max', 'min','default']).sort_values(['country','region']).reset_index(drop=True)

    for ridx,i in enumerate(d1['value']):
        if pd.isnull(i):
            d1['value'].loc[ridx] = d1['value'].loc[ridx-1]
        else:
            pass
    d2 = d1
    d1['key'] = 1
    d2['key'] = 1
    d3 = pd.merge(d1, d2, on='key')

    d3 = d3.drop(['key'],axis=1)

    for index, row in d3.iterrows():
        if d3['region_x'].loc[index] == d3['region_y'].loc[index] and d3['country_x'].loc[index] == d3['country_y'].loc[index]:
            pass
        else:
            d3 = d3.drop([index])
    d3 = d3.reset_index(drop=True)

    d3['rate'] = ""

    for index, row in d3.iterrows():
        if d3['country_x'].loc[index] == 'A':
            d3['rate'].loc[index] = d3['value_x'].loc[index]
        else:
            d3['rate'].loc[index] = d3['value_y'].loc[index]

    d3 = d3.drop(['value_x','country_y','region_y','value_y'],axis=1)

    d3.columns = ['country','region','Option1','Option2','measure']
    d3 = d3[['country','region','measure','Option1','Option2']] 
    return d3
```

```
def new(data):
    d1 = pd.melt(data, id_vars=['country','region'], value_vars=['max', 'min','default']).sort_values(['country','region']).reset_index(drop=True)

    #fill NaN in column value method ffill (propagate last valid observation forward to next valid)
    d1['value'] = d1['value'].fillna(method='ffill')

    d1['key'] = 1
    #you can use double d1
    d3 = pd.merge(d1, d1, on='key')
    d3 = d3.drop(['key'],axis=1)

    #filter columns by conditions - boolean indexing
    d3 = d3[(d3['region_x'] == d3['region_y']) & (d3['country_x'] == d3['country_y'])].reset_index(drop=True)

    #if condition is true get value_x else value_y
    #if neccesarry, convert to int by astype(int)
    d3['rate'] = np.where(np.in1d(d3['country_x'], 'A'), d3['value_x'],d3['value_y']).astype(int)  

    d3 = d3.drop(['value_x','country_y','region_y','value_y'],axis=1)

    d3.columns = ['country','region','Option1','Option2','measure']
    d3 = d3[['country','region','measure','Option1','Option2']]
    return d3


print old(data)
print new(data1)
```

```
print (new(data1) == old(data)).all()
country    True
region     True
measure    True
Option1    True
Option2    True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael. Will check and let you know.

Comment: One question  from my side is that,is there a smart way to take 2nd previous value in the statement d1['value'] = d1['value'].fillna(method='ffill') that we are using?This is because of the sort order that gets disturbed on my final data.

Comment: Yes, before `melt` add `data['default'] = data['min']` and then remove `fillna`. Then solution is faster - `In [73]: %timeit new(data1)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.06 ms per loop`

Comment: If i sort the columns as d3 = d3.sort(['country','Option1','Option2','region'])
I get option in ascending order.But I am looking for specific order of min (all its combinations),max (all) and then default.It that possible?

Comment: Hard question, sorry. Maybe you can create new question. Dont forget add sample data, what you try (d3 = d3.sort(['country','Option1','Option2','region'])) and desired output. Is it OK?

Comment: Sure jezrael..will do that.